# Flutter Camera bad quality

Tags: dart, android-camera, flutter, flutter-plugin

i got the Flutter Camera working with a preview and all that. But the quality of the recorded video is way to bad. I get 1MB for 10 seconds. The resolution is fine (1080 x 1440), but i think the bitrate is way to low somehow.

I looked into the CameraPlugin:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/CameraPlugin.java

```
 mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
 mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1024 * 1000);
 mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
```

Is this the normal configuration and does it work for you guys?
I got a Oneplus 2 and normal camera is taking better videos.

I'm not used to the flutter Method Channel so i can't create my own CustomCameraPlugin and change the important values.

Maybe there is a whole different approach.
Let me know

Greetings Markus

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding. Are you setting camera resolution to high? like so   `new CameraController(_cameraDescriptions[0], ResolutionPreset.high);`

Comment: Yes im doing that.
But this function only responds to:
`case "high":
            minPreviewSize = new Size(1024, 768);
            break;
`
The actual size is then computed in:
`computeBestPreviewAndRecordingSize`

That is all working fine. Has something to do with the bitrate...

Comment: @Markus Hey, I'm having the same problem. The video quality is very poor. Did you found any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Changing `mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate` from `1024 * 1000` to `3000000` for worked for me for better quality.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/CameraPlugin.java